# PHP Object Instantiation

Tags: php

What is the difference between creating a new Object as:

```
$myObject = new OtherObject;
```

and

```
$myObject = new OtherObject();
```

?

Comment: Two characters.

Comment: Difference is that the `__construct()` of the second example can take some arguments…

Comment: No difference at all

Comment: I also tested - for curiosity - if maybe constructor function might not be called. That's not the case. So no diff.